# Failed transaction (Error encountered during contract execution) on Uniswap Router02?

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap

I wish to send a transaction for a Uniswap swap with a path of 3 tokens: [weth, dai, chainlink].
The transaction is mined, but fails, and the error message is not enough for me to debug:

```
fail:  Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]
```

https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x50028fa99475e55cbdfc2de2a5ee3e2f7df10419d437ac7e08f85e627503e8eb

Looking at the [internal transactions](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x50028fa99475e55cbdfc2de2a5ee3e2f7df10419d437ac7e08f85e627503e8eb#internal), it seems a transaction from Router02 to the pair address weth-dai is failing, although I had pre-approved Router02 to be able to send weth (see [Router02 weth approval tx](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xfb70870d31c23ec21627b7bba86b895509ea700a4cb942bd956a2631d3fbdd1c)).

Why is this transaction failing, and how can I debug this?

The transaction part of my code is here:

```
const init = async () => {
  // Fetch the existing pair of tokens = Uniswap exchange
  const weth = WETH[chainId];
  const dai = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, daiAddress);
  const chainlink = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, chainlinkAddress);
  
  const pair_weth_dai = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(dai, weth, provider);
  const pair_dai_chainlink = new Pair(new TokenAmount(dai, '2000000000000000000'), new TokenAmount(chainlink, '1000000000000000000'));
  
  console.log("pair_weth_dai volumeToken0 = ", pair_weth_dai.reserve0.toSignificant(6));
  console.log("pair_weth_dai volumeToken1 = ", pair_weth_dai.reserve1.toSignificant(6));

  console.log("pair_dai_chainlink volumeToken0 = ", pair_dai_chainlink.reserve0.toSignificant(6));
  console.log("pair_dai_chainlink volumeToken1 = ", pair_dai_chainlink.reserve1.toSignificant(6));

  const route_weth_dai = new Route([pair_weth_dai], weth);
  
  const trade = new Trade(route_weth_dai, new TokenAmount(weth, ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01")), TradeType.EXACT_INPUT);
  const slippageTolerance = new Percent('50', '10000');// 0.005 = 0.5%
  
  const amountOutMin = 0;
  const amountOutMinHex = ethers.BigNumber.from(amountOutMin.toString()).toHexString();

  // path with 3 addresses
  const path = [weth.address, dai.address, chainlink.address];
  
  const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20;
  const value = trade.inputAmount.raw;
  const inputAmountHex = ethers.BigNumber.from(value.toString()).toHexString(); 
  const amountInHex = ethers.BigNumber.from(value.toString()).toHexString();


  // ========================
  // swapTokensForExactTokens
  // ========================
  Router02_address = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D";
  const account = signer.connect(provider);
  
  const uniswap = new ethers.Contract(Router02_address,
    ['function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts)'],account);
  
    gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();

  const tx = await uniswap.swapExactETHForTokens(
    amountOutMinHex,
    path,
    to,
    deadline,
    {
      value: inputAmountHex, 
      gasPrice: gasPrice.toHexString(),
      gasLimit: ethers.BigNumber.from(300000).toHexString()
    }
  );
  
  console.log(`Transaction hash: ${tx.hash}`);

  const receipt = await tx.wait();

  console.log(`Transaction was mined in block ${receipt.blockNumber}`);
}

init();
```

The reserves seem sufficient for an input of 0.01 ETH:

```
pair_weth_dai volumeToken0 =  59.24
pair_weth_dai volumeToken1 =  1.75332
pair_dai_chainlink volumeToken0 =  1
pair_dai_chainlink volumeToken1 =  2
```